# Product of Matrix and its Transpose

Tags: matrices

I can't see how to prove the following:

$MM^t = M^tM$

For any square matrix $M$.

I think I was able to do it using index notation, but I'd prefer a proof without using it. (Or if that's the only one you can think of -- would you be willing to share so I can check mine?)

Comment: If you want your proof checked, then please write it up.

Comment: This isn't true.

Comment: Maybe you want to show that $\operatorname{trace} M M^t = \operatorname{trace} M^t M$?

Comment: Matrices with the special property that they commute with their transpose are called [normal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$M=\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&2\\
3&4
\end{matrix}\right)$$
$$\begin{align}
MM^T&\overset{?}{=}M^TM\\
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&2\\
3&4\\
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&3\\
2&4\\
\end{matrix}\right)&\neq\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&3\\
2&4\\
\end{matrix}\right)\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&2\\
3&4\\
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{align}\\$$

The equation for the top left element as an example:
$$1^2+2^2=5\neq1^2+3^2=10$$

Comment: This is helpful because it also shows that the statement is not true for M non-singular.

Comment: It shows it for this particular 2x2 example matrix, which happens to possibly be non-singular (I don't even know and haven't checked). This matrix might also be semi-herbertic, strictly slant-jacksonian and monotonic blue (for some fahrenheit of lower degree) plus whatever else matrices can and cannot be, but it does not show that the statement is true **for all** semi-herbertic, strictly slant-jacksonian, monotonic blue and non-singular matrices.

Answer (score 8):

This is not true. Take $M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, which gives $M^t = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $M M^t = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ but $M^t M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$.

Maybe you wanted to show that $\operatorname{trace} M M^t = \operatorname{trace} M^t M$?

Comment: No it was the product -- I can show they are similar. Thanks!

Comment: @yoshi Could you please edit your original question with your proof so we can check it, as it is highly unlikely that both $M^tM = MM^t$ and $MM^t \neq M^tM$.